# NGINX alias with HHVM

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, fastcgi, hhvm

I'm trying to reroute one of my web directories to another project directory in the home folder. But when I try and access the page, I get served a blank file

I believe the fault in on the `try_files $uri $uri/ /rtstaging/index.php?$query_string;` line. But I'm new to using nginx, so any help would be much appreciated

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /home/default/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name nu-voo.co.uk www.nu-voo.co.uk;
    include hhvm.conf;

    location /rtstaging/ {
            alias  /home/rtsearch/public/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /rtstaging/index.php?$query_string;
            include hhvm.conf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `error.log` when accessing the page?

Comment: Why do you include `hhvm.conf` twice?